# Como puedo agregar al validator un campo llamado telefono? Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

Estoy teniendo un problema al querer agregar mi campo `telefono` en el `validator` de la tabla `user` en el controlador `RegisterController`

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'telefono' => 'required|string|telefono|max:100|unique:users',

    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
    ]);
}
```

No veo cual es el error o si estoy pasando por alto algo pero me lanza el error:

> BadMethodCallException Method [validateTelefono] does not exist.

Comment: No existe un regla de validación llamada "telefono" [puede revisar algunas reglas disponibles aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules)

Comment: Ahh comprendo.. lo que hice fue usar otro nombre que vi en la documentación que me pasaste y me funciono.. gracias amigo